# Can c++ input separator be changed from space to dot?

Tags: c++, cin

exactly, I want to write a program to transfer IP address to its binary format like 202.117.1.20.So is there a way that can make input separated by dot so that I can read 202 as int but not string?
Modify: why the input stream separatd by space, can I change it to dot,or any character I like?

Comment: You might be interested in [`inet_addr`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) or a related function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961189/separating-input-on-forward-slash-in-c/12961404#12961404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious possibility would be something like:

```
unsigned o1, o2, o3, o4;

char dot1, dot2, dot3;

infile >> o1 >> dot1 >> o2 >> dot2 >> o3 >> dot3 >> o4;

assert(dot1=='.' && dot2=='.' && dot3=='.');
assert(o1 < 256 && o2 < 256 && o3 < 256 && o4 < 256);
```

If you really don't want to explicitly read the `.` characters, you can create a ctype facet that classifies `.` as whitespace, then create a locale using that facet, and imbue the stream with that locale.

If you need to write a lot of code that ignores `.` in the input, this might be worthwhile. I've posted such a facet in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370154/179910). Here you'd use that, but read `int`s (or `unsigned`, etc.) instead of strings.